# What does comma mean in an IP address like [aa.bb.cc.dd,eeee]?

Tags: ip

I've got such an IP address from a hosting company as a means to connect to SQL Server remotely. This has always worked.

I understand the IP part but what's with the last part after the comma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the 16-bit TCP/UDP port number.

Comment: Shouldn't port number be specified as :port? What's different with a comma?

Comment: @someuser [.NET requires that you specify the port number with a comma, not the usual (and standard) colon.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/damianm/archive/2003/10/02/236.aspx). It appears to be a .NET/MSSQL quirk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294721/how-to-specify-a-port-number-in-sql-server-connection-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89576/how-do-you-specify-a-different-port-number-in-sql-management-studio

Comment: Never knew this thing...